# Why does exporting labels with buffers take so long?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layouts

I set white borders for text (city names) in qgis. If I export the map without white borders it exports quite quickly (png 600 dpi). If I set the white borders it takes hours! Is there any way I can avoid this?

Best

---

the qgis Version is Lisboa. Operation system Linux. The text labels are set in the regular Text Tab of the Layer-Properties. See [screenshot http://www.projektidee.org/images/extern/qgis2.png](http://www.projektidee.org/images/extern/qgis2.png). In the map composer I didn't change any settings.

Comment: Please give more details on what you mean by 'text.' Is it a label? If so, in what part of the program (map canvas or print composer)? If a label, which labeling tool: regular or advanced? By border, I'm guessing you mean 'buffer'? Which version of QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

I have a theory based on a discussion about old and new labeling engine and their differences (I'll try to find it again):

In old labeling (which you seem to be using based on your screenshot), buffers are create by copying the label multiple times and offsetting it a little in all directions. This means that there are many more objects on the map if buffering is on. This could cause the export to take much more time.

I would give new labeling from label toolbar a try. I think it uses a different technique.

**Update:** This bug report seems to be related ["Label Buffers Produces Extremely Bloated PDF Export"](http://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/ticket/3467)

Comment: Agree, use the new labelling anyway. Work is being done on it and so the old one will be almost certainly dropped in the next release (finally).

Comment: underdark is correct about a [different technique in the new labeling engine for creating buffers](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/src/core/qgspallabeling.cpp#L1536). While this works well for buffers, the QPainterPath technique causes text to be output as non-text, vector objects, much like choosing a 'Create Outlines' action on text in a graphics programs like Illustrator. This means the text is not editable on output from QGIS to PDF and SVG.

Answer (score 1):

The new labeling engine seems to work a lot better (`Layer | Labeling` menu, not the label tab from 'properties'). Just tested this (exporting PDFs from the map composer) on a layer with 246 labelled points using various combinations of buffers (white borders) and the labeling engines.

- Old engine / no buffer: ~ 1 second, 435 KB file;
- Old engine / buffered: **crashed QGIS twice**, no output;
- New engine / no buffer: ~ 1 second, 341 KB file;
- New engine / buffered: ~ 1 second, 446 KB file.

Underdark's theory looking correct at this point - stick to new engine!

**However** - I couldn't get the new engine to rotate the labels 45° for this test.

(QGIS 1.8 on MacOSX, 8GB RAM)

Comment: The label's rotation 'independent of setting data-defined field mappings' is a known issue, and has not yet been addressed in the new labeling engine (see issue [#6118](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/3651)).